# Remove elements that has duplicate adjacent characters from a hashset

Tags: java, hashset

A Hashset consist of elements like below

```
[ABAB,BABA,ABBA,AABB,BBAA,BAAB]
```

I need to remove the elements which has adjacent elements as same

```
in this case the elements are ABBA,AABB,BBAA,BAAB

so the resultant output should be [ABAB,BABA]
```

Below is the code i used to get the values of the Hashset when i give the input as AABB

```
   public static Set<String> crunchifyPermutation(String str) {
    Set<String> crunchifyResult = new HashSet<String>();
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (str.length() == 0) {
        crunchifyResult.add("");
        return crunchifyResult;
    }

    char firstChar = str.charAt(0);
    String rem = str.substring(1);
    Set<String> words = crunchifyPermutation(rem);
    for (String newString : words) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= newString.length(); i++) {
            crunchifyResult.add(crunchifyCharAdd(newString, firstChar, i));
        }
    }
    return crunchifyResult;
}

public static String crunchifyCharAdd(String str, char c, int j) {
    String first = str.substring(0, j);
    String last = str.substring(j);
    return first + c + last;
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem ? does it not work ? any errors ?

Comment: This piece of code returns [ABAB,BABA,ABBA,AABB,BBAA,BAAB] but i need to modify it to return only the two elements [ABAB,BABA] which does not contain adjacent duplicate characters..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are having no problems generating the permutations in the set. You are only asking for help in identifying strings that have equal adjacent characters. If that's correct then:

```
private boolean hasAdjacent(String value) {
    for (int i = 1; i < value.length(); i++) {
        if (value.charAt(i) == value.charAt(i-1))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you are using Java 8 then you can use this to remove the items in one statement:

```
set.removeIf(this::hasAdjacent);
```

Otherwise you can test before you add to the set.

Comment: thanks for the help. But in this case i need to delete the strings in the hash set which has adjacent characters as same

Answer (score 0):

At first you can write method that checks if String contains adjacent same characters:

```
private boolean containsAdjacent(String s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i+1)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And after that you can use this method to write another method that goes through your set and only returns strings that doesn't containt adjacent same characters:

```
private Set<String> work(Set<String> set) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String s : set) {
        if(!containsAdjacent(s)) result.add(s);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you test it like this:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
mySet.add("ABAB");
mySet.add("BABA");
mySet.add("ABBA");
mySet.add("AABB");
mySet.add("BBAA");
mySet.add("BAAB");
Set<String> noAdjacents = work(mySet);
for(String s : noAdjacents) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Then it outputs only `ABAB` and `BABA`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure your `String`'s only contain `A` and `B`, you may use the following.

```
set.removeIf(x -> x.contains("AA") || x.contains("BB"));
```

Otherwise, here is a solution using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add("ABAB");
    set.add("BABA");
    set.add("ABBA");
    set.add("AABB");
    set.add("BBAA");
    set.add("BAAB");

    System.out.println(set); // [BABA, ABAB, ABBA, AABB, BAAB, BBAA]

    set.removeIf(x -> {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < x.length() - 1 ; i++){
         if (x.charAt(i) == x.charAt(i+1)) {
             return true;
         }
    }
    return false;});

    System.out.println(set); // [BABA, ABAB]
}
```

Comment: To Use Collectors which import i need to use?

Comment: @BalajiKarthick `import java.util.stream.Collectors;
`